# animate scroll isn't working at first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[Here is my fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/197/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.subMenu li a').click(function(){
        jQuery('ul.subMenu li a.curM').removeClass('curM');
        jQuery(this).addClass('curM');

        var target = $(this).attr('href');

        var getHeaderHeight = jQuery(".header_wrap.fixed_nav_menu").outerHeight();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': $(target).offset().top - getHeaderHeight}, 'fast', 'swing'); 


    });

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {                
        jQuery('.header_wrap').addClass('fixed_nav_menu');
        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
            jQuery('.header_wrap').removeClass('fixed_nav_menu');   
        }
    });

});
```

At first when you click on for example "The Team", it doesn't scroll to corresponding section but when you click second time it scrolls to corresponding section.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/199/ check this.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan , if you have solved the Question.  Please include your answer and how you solved the problem. 

Your JSFiddle works awesome, but the user may not understand what you've changed without close comparison.

Comment: @aidaghazaryan.  accept correct answer if it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It currently doesn't work because when you add the `fixed_nav_menu` class, it causes the other contents to stick to the top, making `$(target).offset.top` off by the height of your header. This happens because you add the class on scroll which happens after the destination is calculated, causing the destination to be inaccurate for the current state of the page. By changing your calculation to `$(target).offset().top - getHeaderHeight - (getHeaderHeight * !$(".header_wrap").hasClass("fixed_nav_menu"))`, you check whether or not the class is there before calculating and accommodate accordingly.

Also, when you calculate `getHeaderHeight`, you use the selector `jQuery(".header_wrap.fixed_nav_menu")` which returns null. This is because when you're scrolled to the top, the `header_wrap` doesn't have the class `fixed_nav_menu` so the selector will return nothing. To fix this, remove the `.fixed_nav_menu` from the selector, resulting in `jQuery(".header_wrap").height()` to get the height of your header in all cases.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ocahtdgv/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use this. http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/NXzcx/204/

Edited: code has optimized.

Some values defined every time in your code. It is not optimum way.

```
//you should define first time
var headerWrap = jQuery(".header_wrap"),
    getHeaderHeight = jQuery(".header_wrap").outerHeight(),
    fixedNavMenu = "fixed_nav_menu";


$('ul.subMenu li a').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('curM')
        .parent().siblings()
        .children().removeClass('curM');

    var target = $(this).attr('href'),
        offsetTop = $(target).offset().top - (headerWrap.is('.' + fixedNavMenu) ? getHeaderHeight : 2 * getHeaderHeight);

    $('html, body')
        .stop()
        .animate({'scrollTop': offsetTop}, 'fast', 'swing');
});

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    headerWrap.addClass(fixedNavMenu);
    if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
        headerWrap.removeClass(fixedNavMenu);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you edit the HTML?  If so, I would recommend simply keeping the header fixed and adding a spacer div to the top of your page, overlapping the menu.  That will simplify things dramatically.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1c4h8bmp/

As you can see, I have added the following at the beginning of your HTML:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

As well as adding the `.fixed_nav_menu` class to your `header_wrap` div.

While the other answers work, I think this is the simplest approach.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Can you explain?  It's working fine for me on Chrome 43.

Comment: Hi, @Anthony Hilyard. scroll functionality works fine. but changing `curM` class on menu is not working

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that oversight!  I have updated the fiddle with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/199/)

Some slight changes in your function can fix it.

Add the following.

```
var getHeaderHeight = jQuery(".header_wrap").outerHeight();
if(jQuery(".header_wrap").hasClass('fixed_nav_menu'))
    var scrollTo = $(target).offset().top - getHeaderHeight;
else
    var scrollTo = $(target).offset().top - (getHeaderHeight * 2);
console.log($(target).offset().top +  ' - ' + getHeaderHeight);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': scrollTo
}, 'fast', 'swing');
```